# Vuetify: Disabling autocomplete in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete, vuetify.js

Posting this question/answer for better visibility for those using Vuetify and struggling with autocomplete in Chrome. I've seen a number of answers on this topic. My solution involves generating a random `name` attribute. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the the solution that works for me.

I am generating a random `name` attribute using `uuid` `v4` method. If you rely on name for traditional form data, then obviously this might not work for you unless you keep a map of names -> v4 output. This example below is for my credit card form, but I've also implemented it on my login form.

```
import { v4 } from 'uuid'
```

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="card"
    class="card-input"
    outlined
    :name="v4()"
    label="Credit Card Number"
    :rules="creditCardNumberRules"
    v-mask="[' ####  ####  ####  ####', ' ####  ####  #####  ###']"
/>
```